# Compare NSString with constant #define string: isEqualToString or ==?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

If I need to compare a NSString property with a constant string define by `#define`, can I use double equal sign?

I know that `isEqualToString:` would work, but just wonder if `==` also works, say for the following two scenarios:

Scenario 1:

```
#define BLA @"BLA"
NSString *str1 = BLA;
BOOL equal = self.someStr == BLA;
```

Scenario 2:

```
#define BLA @"BLA"
NSString *str1 = @"BLA";
BOOL equal = self.someStr == BLA;
```

are they the same?

Comment: I assume you meant for one of those scenarios to use `isEqualToString:`.

Comment: @JackLawrence that can be 3rd scenario

Comment: For scenario 1, in a single class file, `==` will almost certainly work.  For scenario 2, in it's simple form, probably.  But if your second `@"BLA"` in scenario 2 is just standing in for, eg, `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"BL%@", @"A"]` then the odds of `==` working are low.

Comment: @hzxu oh yeah I didn't see that you put the #define'd statement in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`==` and `isEqualToString:` are never the same. While `==` may sometimes behave as if it is checking the actual characters in a string, it is completely by chance. The LLVM compiler heavily optimizes string constants however LLVM optimizations are an implementation detail and are subject to change at any time.

`isEqualToString:` - compares individual characters in a string.
`==` - straight up pointer comparison. This only returns true when both `NSString` objects are actually the same instance at the same exact memory location.

Edit: `#define` statements are evaluated before the compiler runs (they are evaluated in the preprocessor). `#define` statements do a straight up search and replace so putting the same thing instead of a `#define` is the same exact thing.

Answer (score 1):

`==` compares for the two addresses being the same.  This may be the case for two short strings, in some specific cases, but is not reliably so.

`isEqualToString:` actually compares the strings to each other.